# How can get emoji from database Mysql string in jquery

Tags: emoji

I am using https://github.com/GittiHab/jquery-emojiarea for insert emoji in our textbox.

After that I have inserted in database and fetch record.

But when i put database record in div structure for feedback display then it show like below.

```
You are good developer :smile:.
```

So Please help me return emoji again.

Code here.

```
$('textarea').emojiarea({
    buttonLabel: 'Add Emoji',
    buttonPosition: 'before'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for judge my question but can you provide me answer please.

Comment: Any one have other jQuery please let me know.